# Froala editor v3 rendering buttons all on one line with no dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I am using v3 and I had it set up working fine for several days. I was using moreButtons so I had dropdown menus of buttons. Then all of a sudden today all the buttons are being rendered on one line and are smaller since it is trying to fit them all. I have no console errors. Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

```
toolbarButtons: {
    // Key represents the more button from the toolbar.
    moreText: {
        // List of buttons used in the group.
        buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'textColor', 'backgroundColor', 'inlineClass', 'inlineStyle', 'clearFormatting'],
        // Alignment of the group in the toolbar.
        align: 'left',
        // By default, 3 buttons are shown in the main toolbar. The rest of them are available when using the more button.
        buttonsVisible: 3
    },
    moreParagraph: {
        buttons: ['alignLeft', 'alignCenter', 'formatOLSimple', 'alignRight', 'alignJustify', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'paragraphFormat', 'paragraphStyle', 'lineHeight', 'outdent', 'indent', 'quote'],
        align: 'left',
        buttonsVisible: 3
    },
    moreRich: {
        buttons: ['insertLink', 'insertImage', 'insertVideo', 'insertFile', 'insertTable', 'fontAwesome', 'specialCharacters', 'embedly', 'insertHR'],
        align: 'left',
        buttonsVisible: 4
    },
    moreMisc: {
        buttons: ['undo', 'redo', 'fullscreen', 'print', 'getPDF', 'spellChecker', 'selectAll', 'help'],
        align: 'right',
        buttonsVisible: 2
    }
},
```